# Expand on recorded "Text To Column" macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying (as much for my learning as for a functional macro) to turn my recorded macro into the following function.

I get the error "No data was selected to parse"

I think my problem is `Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, (cNum + 1)).Select` in the second Sub. I don't know if `"iDel"` is a problem the way I have it written as I have not got past how to change `Destination:=Range("I1")`

Where:

`cNum` is the column to be parsed
`iCol` is the number of columns to insert
`iDel` is the parsing delimiter
`iSn` in the Sheet Number

Any insight is helpful

*This is the Fixed version2:*
(This is the last version ( I did not know I could put Array in "fTexeToColumn" gave it a try and it worked)

```
Sub TexeToColumn()
'1st is the column to be parsed
'2nd is the number of columns to insert
'3rd is the parsing delimiter
'4th is the Sheet Number
'Array Set New Col Header Names, add as many name as 2nd parameter is equal to

fTexeToColumn "8", "3", "[", "2", Array("New Col Name1", "New Col Name2", "New Col Name3")

End Sub

Sub fTexeToColumn(cNum As Long, iCol As Long, iDel As String, iSn As Long, Headers As Variant)
'cNum is the column to be parsed
'iCol is the number of columns to insert
'iDel is the parsing delimiter
'iSn is the Sheet Number

 Dim i As Long
 Dim BaseWks As Worksheet

 '~~> Set your sheet here
 Sheets(iSn).Select

 '~~>Adding Columns
 For colx = 1 To iCol Step 1
 Columns(cNum + colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
 Next

 '~~>Column to be parsed
 Columns(cNum).Select

'~Set destination range here
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, (cNum + 1)), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
  :=iDel, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'~~>Delete original column
Columns(cNum).Delete

'Set Header Names
 Set BaseWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(iSn)

  For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
  BaseWks.Cells(1, i + cNum) = Headers(i)
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to turn it into what?  You showed us what doesn't work, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks pnuts that fix every thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP correctly identified two problems:

i)  Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, (cNum + 1)).Select and
ii) iDel

For the former `.Select` is a syntax error (by the time of “Set destination range” the column has already been selected) and for the latter `iDel` has been defined as the `[` string whereas use of `"iDel"` would work if the required delimiter were `i` (since a single character is all that is permitted as a delimiter with Text To Columns).

The fix, as now reflected in the OP, is delete `.Select` and the quotation marks around `iDel`.